# How should valid SQL values be mapped?

Tags: sql, validation

Lets say I have a table containing flowers, where one column would be "color". I constantly receive feed files with data about flowers, (lets say each species have their own id which i check against my database and update that row. From the feed file i also  receive flowers color (this obv. Wouldnt change in real life but for the sake of argument lets say it might). Now i need to make sure that the value of that color field is a valid color and not "asdasd" for example.So my question is how and where should i keep an array of valid colors against which I check and how to store them in table (convert those names to numbers and store those maybe?) I know color can be presented in rgb value and that makes it easy, but lets say it comes from the feed as a string.

Should these type of "validity check maps" for SQL be stored as their own table or maybe as constants in scripts? I know there isnt a one right anwser for this, but I'm curious to hear different approaches on how this would be handled.

Comment: I think you might want to use a Foreign Key Constraint on the data column that represents color. This will strictly enforce the value is one of the available/valid options.

Comment: As far as how to check that data being passed in is valid... I suggest that application layer does the validation tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should these type of "validity check maps" for SQL be stored as their own table

Yes.

> or maybe as constants in scripts?

No

> I know there isn't a one right answer for this

Well, for this one there's a pretty strong best practice.  Have one table that stored "valid" colors with an ID for each color. Then store the ID of the color as part of the flower table.

For example:

```
Colors table:
ID    Name
----  -------
1     Red
2     Blue
3     Yellow
...

Flowers table:
ID    Type     ColorID
---   ------   -------
1     Orchid   2       (Blue Orchid)
2     Rose     1       (Red Rose)
```

The next step would be to "denormalize" the Type as well, but I didn't want to overcomplicate it too much.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Whats your take on database load if there are more fields like this and queries start using more and more tables, would it be scalable? As constants they would be verified before they enter the table and no table joining would be needed. Lets say there are millions of rows and queries can be returning 50,000 rows